# Complex SUM in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hy,

I have 2 tables, Clients and Suppliers with same number of columns

```
Client | Amount | Currency
Supplier | Amount | Currency
```

All clients at one moment in time could be Suppliers and reversal. I would like one query that should calculate to distinct Partner the values from both table by this rule:

```
Client Amount - Supplier Amount = Total Amount
```

and the final table should look like this:

```
Partner | Currency | Amount Client | Amount Supplier | Total Amount
```

The client Table:

```
Client | Amount | Currency
P1     | 100    | EUR
P2     | 50     | USD
P1     | 125    | EUR
P2     | 25     | EUR
```

The Supplier Table

```
Supplier | Amount | Currency
P1       | 75     | EUR
P3       | 125    | USD
P2       | 50     | EUR
P1       | 75     | USD
```

The expected output should be:

```
Partner | Currency | Amount to receive | Amount to pay | Total amount
P1      | EUR      | 225               | 75            | 150
P1      | USD      | 0                 | 75            | -75
P2      | EUR      | 25                | 50            | -25
P2      | USD      | 50                | 0             | 50
P3      | USD      | 0                 | 125           | -125
```

Comment: Are Client and Supplier and Partner the same ID?

Comment: The Partner/Client relationship is unclear. Please post a sample of records from both tables and a sample of what the output rows look like given those two sample input table.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: If someone is at the start of using stackoverflow, DO YOU think that a negative response from users more advanced would bring a PLUS to this site? I think you should retract that minus from this question, if you think you can answer you should just do that.

Comment: @rosuandreimihai I did not downvote. I asked for clarification on your question, to help you improve it so that you could _avoid_ downvotes from others.  You added part of what I asked for, but not the most important part - a sample of what you expect the query output to be.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I have added the desired output

Comment: @rosuandreimihai Thanks for posting the output. I formulated an answer based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing a `UNION ALL` between the two tables you can get a full list of all possible partner codes, along with their respective amounts and currencies.

However, that is not enough to differentiate their roles.  Add a column inside the `UNION` query which supplies a simple static string identifying whether the role was as `Client` or `Supplier`. The outer query can then summarize those using `CASE` inside of `SUM()` aggregates to determine which roles to add up.

**[Here is a demonstration of this in action...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0104f/9)**

```
SELECT 
  Partner,
  Currency,
  -- Based on the static string value added in the UNION, determine
  -- whether Amount should be summarized, or just add 0
  -- This results in zeros instead of NULL for empty values, so it 
  -- has the added benefit of not requiring COALESCE()
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Client' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Amount to receive`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Supplier' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Amount to pay`,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Client' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
  - SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Supplier' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)) AS `Total amount`
FROM (
  -- A UNION ALL combines all the Client/Supplier rows
  SELECT
    -- With a static string column added to identify the role
    -- (the source table)
    'Client' AS type,
    Client AS Partner,
    Amount,
    Currency
  FROM Client
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Supplier' AS type,
    Supplier AS Partner,
    Amount,
    Currency
  FROM Supplier
) all_cs
GROUP BY 
  Partner,
  Currency
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT
     coalesce(client.Partner, supplier.Partner)  as Partner
    ,coalesce(client.Currency,supplier.Currency) as Currency
    ,coalesce(client.Amount,0)                   as "Amount Client"
    ,coalesce(supplier.Amount,0)                 as "Amount Supplier"
    ,coalesce(client.Amount,0)
    +coalesce(supplier.Amount,0)                 as "Total Amount"

FROM (
    SELECT
         Client      as Partner
        ,Currency
        ,sum(Amount) as Amount
    FROM CLients
    GROUP BY
          Client
        ,Currency
)clients
full outer join (
    SELECT
         Supplier    as Partner
        ,Currency
        ,sum(Amount) as Amount
    FROM CLients 
    GROUP BY
          Supplier 
        ,Currency
)supplier
   on supplier.Partner  = client.Partnr
  and supplier.Currency = client.Currency
```

Comment: My mistake is that I didn't mention that the query must use MYSQL

Comment: @rosuandreimihai: What won't work in MySQL?  I tried to be ANSI standard everywhere.

Comment: The full outer join syntax is not MYSQL

Comment: @rosuandreimihai There is a standard technique for faking it with a UNION - do you know how to do that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the other answer was more appropiate to my needs.